# Wordpress Plugin Not Showing User ID and Page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a plugin in Wordpress where I need the current's user ID, and the ID of the current page. I have tried all the codes I found online but they would either show nothing or make the page not load at all.

For example, when I enter:

```
global $wp_query;
$page = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id = $page->ID;
```

The page does not load at all; just blank white.

The only thing that I found working is if I used a hook, however this only made the IDs be displayed in the content, making it impossible for me to store them in separate variables.

So I entered:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'post_page');

function post_page($content){
global $post;
if($post->post_type == 'page'){
    $content .= '<br /> This item is a page and the ID is: '.$post->ID;
} elseif($post->post_type == 'post') {
    $content .= '<br /> This item is a post and the ID is: '.$post->ID;
}
return $content;
}
```

And the ID shows but it's in the post itself. I can't seem to store them in a variable that I can call whenever I want to.

Comment: why dont u use   <?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?> and  <?php $postid =  get_the_ID(); ?>

Comment: Because this is outside the loop.